# Aspx page making ajax call loading in chrome but not loading in edge or IE browser

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

Aspx page loading chart and making ajax call, it's loading in Chrome but not loading in IE/Edge browser.

It is showing

> This page is having a problem

and other errors message aren't being displayed.

Sample Code

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url:,
            data:,
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            xhrFields: {
                withCredentials: true
            },
            success: (data: any) => {
                let responseData = data;
                for (let i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
                    $('#Art').append($('<div id=' + [i] + '></div>'));                       
                }
                $('.loader').fadeOut('slow');
            },
            error: (data: any) => {
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Can you please attach a sample code?

Comment: $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url:,
                data:,
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: 'json',
                xhrFields: {
                    withCredentials: true
                },
                success: (data: any) => {
      
                },
                error: (data: any) => {
                }
            });
        }